# Difference between Haskell and Idris: Reflection of Runtime/Compiletime in the type universes

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, idris, type-level-computation

So in Idris it's perfectly valid to write the following.

```
item : (b : Bool) -> if b then Nat else List Nat
item True  = 42
item False = [1,2,3] // cf. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWeT_G04a0A
```

Without the type signature, this looks like a dynamically typed language. But, indeed, Idris is dependently-typed. The concrete type of `item b` can only be determined during run-time.

This is, of course, a Haskell-programmer talking: The type of `item b` in the Idris sense is given during compile-time, it is `if b then Nat ...`.

Now my question: Am I right to conclude that in Haskell, the border between the runtime and the compiletime runs exactly between the world of values (False, "foo", 3) and the world of types (Bool, String, Integer) whereas in Idris, the border between the runtime and the compiletime goes across universes?

Also, am I right to assume that even with dependent types in Haskell (using DataKinds and TypeFamilies, cf. [this article](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/konn/prove-your-haskell-for-great-safety/dependent-types-in-haskell)) the above example is impossible in Haskell, because Haskell contrary to Idris does not allow values to leak to the type-level?

Comment: Great question! I'll direct your attention to [this lecture](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ad4BVmPni7A) by @pigworker to supplement his answer

Comment: Can you create an idris-Universe topic/tag and use that instead of universe, which is for the MultiValue Database.

Comment: @Mike "Creating a new tag requires at least 1500 reputation ..."

I guess, an appropriate tag would be "type-universes".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you're right to observe that the types versus values distinction in Idris does not align with the compiletime-only versus runtime-and-compiletime distinction. That's a good thing. It is useful to have values which exist only at compiletime, just as in program logics we have "ghost variables" used only in specifications. It is useful also to have type representations at runtime, allowing datatype generic programming.

In Haskell, `DataKinds` (and `PolyKinds`) let us write

```
type family Cond (b :: Bool)(t :: k)(e :: k) :: k where
  Cond 'True  t e = t
  Cond 'False t e = e
```

and in the not too distant future, we shall be able to write

```
item :: pi (b :: Bool) -> Cond b Int [Int]
item True  = 42
item False = [1,2,3]
```

but until that technology is implemented, we have to make do with singleton forgeries of dependent function types, like this:

```
data Booly :: Bool -> * where
  Truey  :: Booly 'True
  Falsey :: Booly 'False

item :: forall b. Booly b -> Cond b Int [Int]
item Truey  = 42
item Falsey = [1,2,3]
```

You can get quite far with such fakery, but it would all get a lot easier if we just had the real thing.

Crucially, the plan for Haskell is to maintain and separate `forall` and `pi`, supporting parametric and ad hoc polymorphism, respectively. The lambdas and applications that go with `forall` can still be erased in runtime code generation, just as now, but those for `pi` are retained. It would also make sense to have runtime type abstractions `pi x :: * -> ...` and throw the rats' nest of complexity that is `Data.Typeable` into the dustbin.

Comment: GHC 8: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overview-of-type-in-type

" Full dependently typed languages also remove the difference between expressions and types, but doing that in GHC is a story for another day."

Comment: Yes, it *is* a story, for another day, perhaps not so very far away.

Answer (score 9):

> Now my question: Am I right to conclude that in Haskell, the border
>   between the runtime and the compiletime runs exactly between the world
>   of values (False, "foo", 3) and the world of types (Bool, String,
>   Integer) whereas in Idris, the border between the runtime and the
>   compiletime goes across universes?

<s>Idris compiles to [Epic](https://eb.host.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/epic.php)</s> (UPDATE: no, it no longer compiles to Epis as **Spearman** says in the comment below):

> No semantic checking, other than to see if names are in scope --- it
>   is assumed that the higher level language will have performed
>   typechecking, and in any case Epic should make no assumptions about
>   the higher level type system or any transformations you've applied.
>   Type annotations are required, but they only give hints to the
>   compiler (I might change this).

So types do not matter denotationally, i.e. the meaning of a term doesn't depend on its type. Moreover some value level things can be erased, e.g. in `Vect n A` (where `Vect` is the type of lists with statically known length) `n` (the length) can be erased, [because](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/erasure.html)

> There are methods described by Brady, McBride and McKinna in [BMM04](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/erasure.html#bmm04)
>   to remove the indices from data structures, exploiting the fact that
>   functions operating on them either already have a copy of the
>   appropriate index or the index can be quickly reconstructed if needed.

The thing here is that `pi` in Idris acts for types in almost the same way as `forall` in Haskell: they are both parametric (though, these parametricities are different) in this case. A compiler can use types to optimize code, but in both languages control flow doesn't depend on types, i.e. you can't say `if A == Int then ... else ...` (though, if `A` is in canonical form, then you know statically whether it's `Int` or not and hence [can](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/EqType.agda) write `A == Int`, but that still doesn't affect control flow, because all decisions are maken before runtime). The concrete type of `item b` just doesn't matter at runtime.

However as [pigworker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828361/pigworker) says it's not necessarily to be parametric in types. As well as it's not necessarily to be non-parametric in values. Type-level — value-level and parametric — non-parametric are completely orthogonal dichotomies. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26012264/3237465) answer for details.

So Haskell and Idris are different in how they treat value level things wrt runtime/compile content (because in Idris you can mark an argument with `.` to make it erasable), but they treat types in roughly the same way.

Comment: "Idris compiles to Epic"

Is this still the case? The Idris implementation paper (2013) mentions Epic as a compiler backend, but the Idris changelog indicates that dependencies on Epic were removed with Idris 0.9.3 (2012-09-15), almost a year before the paper was published.

The current Idris source code (1.0) doesn't seem to contain any references to "Epic".